# Check value on a particular array index in Vuelidate

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I have the following form array in Vuelidate. But how can I base some validation based on another field's value **on the same array index**.

Below is my none working example, but I want the forename to be required IF something has been entered for the surname.

```
validations: {
        fixturesArray: {
            $each: {
                fixtureName: {
                    //required
                },
                guestDetails: {
                    $each: {
                        forename: {
                            required: requiredIf(function() {
                                return $each.surname != ""
                            })
                        },
                        surname: {

                        },
                        dietaryRequirements: {
                            $each: {
                                name: {

                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let's assume your case is: **Forename is required if surname is not null**

```
validations: {
    fixturesArray: {
        $each: {
            guestDetails: {
                $each: {
                    forename: {
                        requiredIf: requiredIf((obj) => obj.surname != null)
                    },
                    surname: {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use requiredIf in $each like that, although this is not stated in the documentation. The `obj` parameter is the object being validated in this iteration. You can see more information [here](https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/issues/393#issuecomment-513780897).

Hope it helps, cheers.

Comment: This was what I was looking for! Thanks :)